# pycrypto AES with password instead key+iv

Tags: python, cryptography

I need to port this JavaScript code to Python:

```
var decrypt = function (text, password){
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',password);
    var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8');
    dec += decipher.final('utf8');
    return dec;
}
```

The problem is that the PyCrypto library needs a key+IV and not just a password, and I don't know how to imitate the JavaScript `crypto.createDecipher` method.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipher_algorithm_password_options: “The implementation of crypto.createDecipher() derives keys using the OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and no salt.” (If you’re able to change the encryption instead, you should probably do so as recommended in the same documentation.)

Comment: I readed it, but I don't know how to implement it D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have a complete Python 3 solution:

```
def decrypt(text, password):
  key, iv = _evp_bytes_to_key(password, '', 32, 16)
  decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
  return decipher.decrypt(bytes.fromhex(text.strip())).decode('utf8')

def _evp_bytes_to_key(password, salt, key_len, iv_len):
  dtot = hashlib.md5((password + salt).encode()).digest()
  d = [dtot]
  while len(dtot) < (iv_len + key_len):
    d.append(hashlib.md5(d[-1] + (password + salt).encode()).digest())
    dtot = dtot + d[-1]
  return dtot[:key_len], dtot[key_len:key_len+iv_len]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a possible solution is have a file decrypt.js with:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var decrypt = function (text, password){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',password);
  var dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8');
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}
console.log(decrypt(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]));
```

And in your python file just use:

```
def decrypt(text, password):
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        ['nodejs', 'decrypt.js', text, password],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    stdoutdata, stderrdata = p.communicate()
    return stdoutdata.decode('utf8')
```

Probably it's not the best option, but it works.